# Convert bytes in string using python

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, byte, bson

I have bson file, and i dont know what have inside of the document. I see the data type, and conclude the type of data is bytes. So, for undertsand the content the file, i need to save in readable formart.
So, the firt step was convert my bytes in a string.. But, i return the following message:

TypeError: descriptor 'decode' for 'bytes' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

To resolve this, i used the function:
str1 = bytes_content.decode('latin-1') and doesn't return anything. After, i using the:
str2 = bytes_content.decode('cp437').

And after this, i did a print, and doesnt'return anything :(
I stay convert bytes in string in bson file.. For after this, can read this document, because this is bson file

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xhGw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the type object into your bytes_content variable.

```py
bytes_content = read_content["data"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, after run the code: str1 = bytes_content.decode('UTF-8')   i get the following unicodedecodeerror: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte

Comment: You might try with a different encoding like "latin-1"

Comment: I can !! :) Now, i execute the function print(type(str1)), and i return <class 'str'>. :) 
But, when i do print(str1) to see the string not appear anything

Comment: Can you add all your code? Otherwise, it's difficult.

Comment: a update the text and image above. See please..

Comment: @Women_it_2022, by looking at your image it seems you are trying to open a PDF file by using BSON reader in Python. Can you verify? %PDF-1.5 indicates the version of PDF used in the file so...